# Strange properties of the "speak" class

Tags: powershell

I have a code that involves the `System.speech` assembly in a for loop but the errors thrown at me are exceedingly strange from what I've seen.

I have a code that generates 10 random letters and/or numbers  then stores them in an array which I would grab certain elements of and then use the text-to-speech engine. However, I want to have a pause in between each of the speeches but I get thrown the error:

<sup>PS Core 7.1 Error</sup>

```
MethodException:
Line |
  13 |          $speak.speak($say)
     |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "speak" and the argument count: "1".
```

Or

<sup>PS 5.1 Error</sup>

```
Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "speak" and the argument count: "1".
At line:13 char:5
+     $speak.speak($say)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

---

My code is

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.speech
$speak = New-Object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
$set = @(48..57 + 65..90)

for($i=0;$i -lt $set.length; $i++){
    [char]$set[$i] = $set[$i] 
}

$values = $set | get-random -count 10

for($i=0; $i -lt $values.length; $i++){
    $say = $values[$i]
    $speak.speak($say)
    timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK > $null
}
```

I don't understand what the error means in this context, but if I just run

```
$speak.speak($values)
```

It will correctly speak, but however if I try to speak each value of the array one by one, the error occurs 10 times or however many times there are values in the array. Any information on why this error occurs, what the error is called, or anything that can give me more information about how to fix this  would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your script, `$say` is of type `[char]`, but none of the implementations of `Speak()` accept a `[char]` as a parameter - so PowerShell can't decide which one (which overload) to pick!

Convert `$say` to a string before passing it:

```bsh
$speak.Speak("$say")
```

... and now PowerShell will be able to figure out the correct method implementation to execute :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mathias! I tried defining `$say` as a string as you suggested by doing `$say = "$values[$i]"`, but instead, `$say` became equal to `$values` which I don't really understand why that happened. However, if I try your *exact* suggestion, the speak engine will say the exact string "dollar-sign say" ($say) so unfortunately this doesn't work.

Comment: If you want to do it when assigning to `$say`, either do `"$($value[$i])"` or `$value[$i] -as [string]`

Comment: @NekoMusume It's important that you don't mix `'` (single-quotes) and `"` (double-quotes)! `'$say'` will most certainly result in the literal phras "dollar-sign say" being spoken